# show products on cms page under specified category id

Tags: magento

now. in the CMS page i using the following code:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="12" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

on the home page.it ok. it can show all the products under category 12. but now. i want to change some style of it. so i cope the `list.phtml` file to `listhp.phtml` using

```
{{block type="core/templatet" category_id="12"  template="catalog/product/listhp.phtml"}}
```

there is no any products show. why? how to correct it? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your code from:

```
{{block type="core/templatet" category_id="12"  template="catalog/product/listhp.phtml"}}
```

To:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="12"  template="catalog/product/listhp.phtml"}}
```

and everything will be fine, its because the method used in the template file like getLoadedProductCollection() are defined in the block Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List which are called correctly when you set the block type to 'catalog/product_list'.
Also 'core/templatet' is not a valid block, it's 'core/template'.

Comment: well, check your file path, try to echo something in the file, use template path hints to see if the template is getting included in the layout of the home page. The code should work must be some other problem.